# Wordpress theme breaking on anything but home page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, web

so I am building a custom wordpress theme for a client (I am a freelancer, pretty new to wordpress) and I have built the main theme that works 100% on the home page, but when I go into a post, archive, etc, the image path breaks, the sidebar breaks. I have attached photos for you to see: 
[image: This is what it is meant to look like]
And this is what the post looks like:
[image]

======== code edit =======

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

<?php if (is_search()) { ?>
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
<?php } ?>

<title>
       <?php
          if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
             single_tag_title("Tag Archive for &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
          elseif (is_archive()) {
             wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; }
          elseif (is_search()) {
             echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; }
          elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
             wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
          elseif (is_404()) {
             echo 'Not Found - '; }
          if (is_home()) {
             bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
          else {
              bloginfo('name'); }
          if ($paged>1) {
             echo ' - page '. $paged; }
       ?>
</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp-    content/themes/custom1/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">

<!-- HTML 5 shiv -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">

<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="page-wrap">

    <section id="header">

            <div id="logo"></div>

        <div id="nav">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <!-- <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> -->
                        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Nav Menu')); ?>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section> <!-- end of Header -->

    <section id="page">
        <div class="wrapper">
```

index.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="main_content">
                <article>   
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>        </h2>

        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="postmetadata">
            <?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
            Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | 
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
</article>
            </section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and page.php (the buggy one):

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="main_content">
<article>   
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>

        <div class="entry">

            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

        </div>

        <?php edit_post_link('Edit this entry.', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>

    </div>

    <?php // comments_template(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</article>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

sorry for the long post :)

Comment: look at the url paths for the images i imagine they are fine from the homepage but when you navigate into the site the urls stay the same and so the images break.

Comment: But it is the sidebar, the content is the same, file paths are the same

Comment: Yes, but if the path is relative, then the browser may look for it in the wrong place, as the URL for the home and for the post are different.

Comment: But wouldn't the stylesheet still be styling the same elements?

Comment: Hey Josh, you should post some relevant code. Its hard to tell from two screenshots whats going on. YOu should comment out all code from the 'post' page and only add the header. Check if it works. If yes, add the sidebar -- check again. And so on. Something conflicts with your header code and doing it step by step will really help debugging.

Comment: @domdev thank you, I will try that, I have also posted the code. the index.php file works fine, but the page.php does not.

Comment: This may be obvious thing to say :) but I think you are missing a class on a wrapping element. Use the inspector to compare the two pages to see why the style is not being applied (to 'services' for instance)

Comment: I have already done that, nothing missing

Comment: @ScottSimpson It seems that on the main page all links work (ie: wp-content/themes/[mytheme]/...) but when referenced from other pages, the links dont work, thats why the styling is off. What must I do with the links??

Comment: @ScottSimpson ok, so it is the file path's / links, so all other pages work using the "../wp-content/themes/[mytheme]/...)" but then the home page wont find it because the homepage only picks up "wp-content/themes/[mytheme]/..." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer after alot of searching in a random blog post (I forgot where, sorry).

What I was doing: the image only worked on the homepage and no other page if I put the link to the image as: `wp-content/themes/[mytheme]/images/image.jpg`

and it worked on all other pages but not the home page when I put the following: `../wp-content/themes/[mytheme]/images/image.jpg`

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/image1.jpg
```

So thank you to Nicholas King, George Marques, Domdev and Scott Simpson for putting me on the right track.

Thanks,
Josh